# Express GraphQL - End to end testing

Tags: node.js, express, testing, apollo-server, supertest

I have server side app based on `Typescript`, `Express`, `Passport`, `Mongoose` and `Apollo Server`. I am using `Mocha`, `Chai`, `Sinon` and `Supertest` for testing the app. I am able to write unit tests for individual functions but if try to do `end to end` testing using `supertest's request` method it's not working as expected.

Main challenge is, test never goes to `app.use` callbacks, but result is `success` always.

I have tried many examples from google, offical docs of Apollo server and supertest, but none worked for my app structure.

I tried using `httpServer`, `apolloServer` and `app` instances as `supertest`'s `request()` argument, but none worked.

**Here is my test file**:

```js
// index.test.ts
import { Server } from 'http';
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../src/app';
import { startApolloServer } from '../src/apolloServer';

describe('index', () => {
    let httpServer: any;

    before(async () => {
        httpServer = new Server(app.app);
        await startApolloServer(httpServer, { app: app.app });
    });

    describe('new App()', () => {
        it('Should initiate App successfully', (done) => {
            request(httpServer).post(`http://localhost:4001${process.env.GRAPHQL_PATH}`).expect(200);
            return done();
        });
    });
});
```

**Here is my app structure**:

```js
// index.ts
const { Server } = require('http');
require('dotenv').config();
const { app } = require('./app').default;
const { startApolloServer } = require('./apolloServer');

require = require('esm')(module);

// Start the HTTP Server
const httpServer = new Server(app);

export default startApolloServer(httpServer, { app });
```

```js
// app.ts
import express, { Application, NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import passportAuthorizer from './express/authorizer';
import validateCredentials from './express/validate-credentials.middleware';
import validateToken from './express/validate-token.middleware';

class App {
    public app: Application;
    public passport = passport;

    constructor() {
        this.app = express();
        this.configure();
    }

    private configure() {
        const { app } = this;

        /**
         * Rest of the code....
         */

        app.use(
            `${process.env.GRAPHQL_PATH}`,
            function authenticatorAuthorizor(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
                // This function never get's executed while testing
                if (!req.headers.origin || req.headers.origin === 'http://localhost:4001') {

                    return next();
                }

                if (req.body?.operationName === 'Login') {
                    const result = validateCredentials(req, res, next, passport);
                    return result;
                }

                const result = validateToken(req, res, next, passport);
                return result;
            },
            function authorizer(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
                passportAuthorizer(req, res, next, passport);
            }
        );
    }
}

export default new App();
```

```js
// apolloServer.ts
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground } from '@apollo/server-plugin-landing-page-graphql-playground';
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { ApolloServerPluginCacheControl } from '@apollo/server/plugin/cacheControl';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import authorizerDirective from './directives/authorizer';
import formatError from './formatError';
import myPlugin from './myPlugin';
import resolvers from './schema/resolvers';
import typeDefs from './schema/typeDefs';

const { authorizerDirectiveTransformer, authorizerDirectiveTypeDefs } = authorizerDirective();

const directiveTransformers = [authorizerDirectiveTransformer];

let schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: [authorizerDirectiveTypeDefs, typeDefs],
    resolvers,
});

schema = directiveTransformers.reduce((curSchema, transformer) => transformer(curSchema), schema);

export const startApolloServer = async (httpServer: any, { app }: any) => {
    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer<any>({
        schema,
        csrfPrevention: true,
        plugins: [
            myPlugin,
            ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
            ApolloServerPluginCacheControl({ calculateHttpHeaders: 'if-cacheable' }),
            ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground(),
        ],
        includeStacktraceInErrorResponses: true,
        formatError,
    });

    await apolloServer.start();

    app.use(
        process.env.GRAPHQL_PATH,
        expressMiddleware(apolloServer, {
            context: async ({ req }) => {
                return req.user;
            },
        })
    );

    await httpServer.listen({ port: process.env.PORT });

    return apolloServer;
};
```